# Import specific javascript files as string in react-native with metro bundler

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

- I need to import specific javascript files into a component.
- The content of the javascript is code but needs to be transformed into a string
- I cannot transform it at the runtime
- The content of the file needs to be injected into a web view, so it handles objects like `window`, so currently, it throws an error on import when the code gets interpreted

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case I needed to write a custom transformer.

```js
const babelTransformer = require('metro-react-native-babel-transformer');

module.exports.transform = ({ src, filename, options }) => {
    return babelTransformer.transform({
      src: `let code = ${JSON.stringify(src)}; export default code;`,
      filename,
      options,
    });
};
```